# How to prevent acces to constants in twig?

Tags: twig

There is some security reasons and I want to prevent access to class constants in twig. How can I do it?

**Note:** It is possible to access constants with code below.

```
{{ constant('Entity\\Demo::MY_CONSTANT') }}
```

Comment: My guess is you can't since `const` are public in PHP...what kind of value do you want to hide?

Comment: @cheesemacfly thanks for answer. There must be way to prevent it. I hope someone will answer :)

Comment: You could [overload](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#overloading) the `constant()` function in twig. Seems seriously like a dirty trick tho...

Comment: I will try to overload it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sandbox is not the cure. Because in the system the user writes his own template, this brings security issues.

For that reason function overriding in extension may be a good solution.

```
$environment = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('autoescape' => self::$_autoEscapeOpened));
$myTwigExtension = new MyTwigExtension();
//note that MyTwigExtension extends Twig_Extension
$environment->addExtension($myTwigExtension);

//here is MyTwigExtension
class MyTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
    //in my twig extension, there is a method called getFunctions. If not, write one.

    public function getFunctions() {
        $functions = array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('constant', array($this, 'constant')),
        );
    return $functions;
    }
    //and add the customized constant function in your extension here!
    public function constant($variable){
        return '';
    }
}
```

if you don't want to use extension, see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions

Ant the result is nice, there is no output in the screen, without any sandbox use. (solution is on backend)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this with the Sandbox extension:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#sandbox-extension

This extension allows you to define a security policy which basically has a whitelist of functions, tags, filters...

You can enable sandbox mode globally, or just use sandbox mode for a specific include (default behavior):

```
{% sandbox %}
    {% include 'user.html' %}
{% endsandbox %}
```